# Login and retrieve data from embedded form page using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, post, httpwebrequest

I'm a bit confused on how to go about this as I'm not really conversant with web stuff. I'm using a console application in C# to try and retrieve value from a page link inside a [password protected homepage](http://www.unnportal.com/cp/studentportal/index.htm). [I'm using the following details](http://padfly.com/questiontest)

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("");
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
req.Method = "POST";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
req.KeepAlive = true;
req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
req.Referer = "copy from url";

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

String Username = copy from url;
String PassWord = copy from url;

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
sw.Write(string.Format("&loginname={0}&password={1}&btnSubmit=Log In&institutioncode=H4V9KLUT45AV&version=2", Username, PassWord));
sw.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

However, when I inspect the data retrieved from the web page it shows something like this:

> '...Your Session has timed out due to inactivity.Please logout and
>   relogin.
> return to login page>'

I'm guessing this is due to some VIEWSTATE stuff in ASP.NET
I'm also guessing I might have a problem with retrieving the data from the link I'll extract from the homepage, coz it seems the link simply loads data into a frame rather than reload the webpage.

Anyone please?

Comment: can you supply a user/pass to try?

Comment: It's in the url: http://padfly.com/questiontest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form data is incorrect. After removing the `&` at the beginning it worked for me:

```
sw.Write(string.Format("loginname={0}&password={1}&btnSubmit=Log In&institutioncode=H4V9KLUT45AV&version=2", Username, PassWord));
```

Additionally, as already mentioned in the other answer, you need to add the returned `ASPSESSIONIDSSRRDRST` cookie in further requests to the site.

Comment: Thanks, your code worked, but it left me with a new error: Your browser: "This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them" Any idea how I can resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Okay, later figured out how to resolve the issue. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok... the website is using Cookies, so, after you logged in you need to retrieve the cookies first, to make another WebRequest:

```
CookieCollection cookiesResponse = new CookieCollection();

if (response != null)
{
    foreach (string cookie in response.Headers["Set-Cookie"].Split(';'))
    {
        string name = cookie.Split('=')[0];
        string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
        cookiesResponse.Add(new Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path, domain));
    }
}
```

In you example the cookie contains: ASPSESSIONIDSSRRDRST=FEKODBMDBEIPCLLENCFLFBEA

You must use that CookieCollection for any request to the web, in your request you can set the cookies:

```
request.CookieContainer = cookiesResponse;
```

And finaly, you can parse the response. You can use an html tag parse, or parse the plain text.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: path="/" and domain is the url root, if you debug, put a breakpoint in the foreach, however, thats arguments are optionals.

Comment: Did you try this code yourself, I'm still getting the response: '...Your Session has timed out due to inactivity.Please logout and relogin.<br><A HREF=index.htm>return to login page...'

Comment: check, when you log in to the website, there are four request, and you must do each one of them, to find what are you looking for. Are you using some progran to catch request/response? If no, i suggest Fiddler, is free, and very useful.

Comment: Thanks so much, but it seems Peter was able to find the correct problem.