# HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I`m building an application that need to authenticate session on a website and then submits/retrieved data.

This is what I`ve been able to do till now (through googling). I`ve been able to detect if the requested page actually exists or not, but more than that, I couldn`t proceed!

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/");
try
{
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
        textBlock1.Text = "Connected ...\n Status code is: " + httpResponse.StatusCode;
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
    {
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
        textBlock1.Text = "Error Code: " + httpResponse.StatusCode;
    }
}
```

This code just detects if the web source requested exists or not. Now I`ll assume that the source exists, how can I send username/password to be authenticated?

I`ll assume that the username/password fields are named user/pass simultaneously ... How can I send the username and password to the website to validate and read the response?

I believe that this part will be very helpful throughout the whole development process.

Comment: You need to give us more information. How is the user supposed to be authenticated? Is it via. a basic authentication, Windows authentication or via. the website's own authentication methods?

Comment: How does the website handles authorization? Given your code above I assume that you have to enter the username/password on the page and then hit something like Submit, is that correct?

Comment: @Dominik: This is true, you have to enter the username and password and hit Enter/Submit/whatever .

Comment: @sikas, than its likely that you´ll have to POST your username & password to the site. Have a look a Fiddler and capture the traffic to the site once you click Enter. Check the POST data send to the site (see http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx). You may have to deal with cookies to remain logged on to the site, but thats part two ;)

Comment: @Dominik: This URL is for ASP, does it work for desktop apps?

Comment: @Sikas: Check the paragraph below "How will I do it?", It shows how to create a WebRequest holding POST data. From there it doesn´t matter if you´re creating the Request in a Form/WPF/ASP/WhatsOEver application

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this SO question (and answers): [Login and retrieve data from embedded form page using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713526/login-and-retrieve-data-from-embedded-form-page-using-c/6784371)

You only need to adjust the names of the form fields accordingly to your target site.

Comment: Thanks for that, but does it work for desktop app? as this link is for ASP

Comment: Yes, it does. It makes no difference whether the client is a asp.net app on a server or a desktop app on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Credentials property for the WebRequest object which you can use to send along with the request.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url-here");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: How do you know that his application uses HTTP authentication when no mention of the means of authentication has been disclosed?